# LWC: cache refresh across different components? advanced technicies for cache management?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, cache

Let's say we have 2 LWC components:

1. `createOpportunity` component, which uses Apex to create an Opportunity.
2. `opportunitiesList` which uses `@wire` to get the list of Opportunities for a particular Account.
   (sample code can be found down below)

If I use `createOpportunity` and then navigate to another page that has `opportunitiesList` it won't have the latest created Opportunity.

I want to use `@wire` to improve performance in `opportunitiesList`, but I wasn't able to find a reliable solution to refresh cache across 2 components.

I tried storing information about which methods cache are invalidated in session storage and then trying to `refreshApex` at the start of the component, but it also seems suboptimal.

The only solution so far is to just remove `@AuraEnable(Cacheable=true)` and make the code imperative, but it's also an option that I don't like.

Hopefully, someone figured a way how to deal with this situation.

```
// createOpportunity
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";
import createOpportunity from '@salesforce/apex/OpportunityController.createOpportunity';

export default class CreateOpportunity extends LightningElement {

  async handleSave() {
    await createOpportunity({/*some info */});
  }
}
```

```
// opportunitiesList
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from "lwc";
import getOpportunities from '@salesforce/apex/OpportunityController.getOpportunities';

export default class OpportunitiesList extends LightningElement {

  @api recordId;
  
  @wire(getOpportunities, {recordId: '$recordId'})
  opportunities;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd add the wire method on the other component:

```
// createOpportunity
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";
import createOpportunity from '@salesforce/apex/OpportunityController.createOpportunity';
import getOpportunities from '@salesforce/apex/OpportunityController.getOpportunities';

export default class CreateOpportunity extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getOpportunities, {recordId: '$recordId'})
    opportunities;
    recordId;

  async handleSave() {
    this.recordId = await createOpportunity({/*some info */});
    return refreshApex(this.opportunities);
  }
}
```

Remember, LDS shares the cache across all components, so by triggering it on one component, other components will automatically get the update.

Comment: I also thought so, but during initial testing, it didn't work. I'll check again and add another comment

Comment: Thanks, you're right as usual) The trick is that you need to pass the same `method` parameters for both pages, otherwise it wouldn't refresh results

Comment: still don't know how to do this elegantly, because caching issues can happen in multiple places in the application.